# Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am now convinced that there is no solution to this. But in case there is someone out there who can help: Whole Element that I want to click on genesys cloud is (Its a part of a table):

```html
<a target="_blank" data-bind="
                    attr: {
                        href: lastReportRun().reportUrl
                    },
                    lAttr: {
                        title: 'reports.list.grid.downloadColumn.fileTypes.' + lastReportFileType()
                    },
                    lString: 'reports.list.grid.downloadColumn.fileTypes.' + lastReportFileType()
                " href="https://apps.usw2.pure.cloud/platform/api/v2/downloads/9161911a0307202a" title="XLSX">XLSX</a>
```

Element snapshot:

[image]

I am trying to locate this element to click on it and start downloading the .xlsx file. These are the things I have tried so far, but no luck. Can someone please help me understand where I can correct it.

Code trials:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "XLSX"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("XLSX").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//a[text()="XLSX"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[normalize-space(text())="XLSX').click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='XLSX' and @value='XLSX']").click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*input[@name='XLSX' and @value='XLSX']"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/a').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*span[contains(., 'XLSX')]"))).click()

l=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*a[@title='XLSX']")
l.click()
```

Comment: The link is probably in iframe

Comment: better show real url for this HTML so we could see full HTML and test code on real HTML.

Comment: @JaSON Yes, looks like it. I tried WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath, still  didnt work

Comment: You should pass exact locator of iframe into `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` as argument

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic *`<a>`* element.

So to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "XLSX"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='https://apps.usw2'][title='XLSX'][data-bind]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, 'https://apps.usw2') and text()='XLSX'][@title='XLSX' and @data-bind]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I tried these, but these are giving me timeout exception, I have also tried adjusting the wait time, still...